# Flutter app which runs tensorflow model freezes or crashes - too heavy computation

Tags: android, tensorflow

Flutter app which runs tflite (tensorflow) model freezes or crashes - too heavy computation - almost on any Android device.

Can we benefit from switching to native Java android app? Or performance with tflite computation is basically same for both platforms?

Comment: Honestly there isn't enough information here. Flutter has its own render engine which may/may not cause memory problems for your particular application/set of user features. I would test out the TFlite model on a Java/Kotlin to see if that changes anything but as written there are too many unknown things.

Comment: @MorrisonChang it is expensive to make java app just to test if it works any better. The main thing that it hangs or crashes when runs tflite model

Comment: "Expensive" is relative if you aren't writing mobile apps directly. Again without details like app features, tensorflow model info like prebuilt or custom and crash log, not sure what help you are expecting. StackOverflow is for specific programming questions, not a general software development forum.